# Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Insert' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba, loops, runtime

I am attempting to track changes in our financial models. The aim is to identify who is back solving.

I have written code that executes until I switch from one sheet to only one other specific sheet.

```vb
Sub tracker()

    Dim Cell As Range
        
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Input check IC").Range("AI2:AI128")
        If Cell.Value <> 0 Then
            With Sheets("Copy IC")
                Sheets("Change tracker").Range("C10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 33).Value = .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, "A"), .Cells(Cell.Row, "AG")).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next
            
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Input check IC").Range("AI2:AI128")
        If Cell.Value <> 0 Then
            With Sheets("Live IC")
                Sheets("Change tracker").Range("C10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 33).Value = .Range(.Cells(Cell.Row, "A"), .Cells(Cell.Row, "AG")).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next
                
    'Live IC
    Sheets("Live IC").Range("B2:AG128").Copy
    Sheets("Copy IC").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

I have a duplicate code for "RC" where: IC = investment case ; RC = reference case. RC is called from tracker 2 in a separate module.

The code executes perfectly when I go to any sheet in the workbook, other than RC (from IC)/ IC (from RC). I might add the code is called when the sheet is deactivated. I feel the code is stuck in a loop when I deactivate/active IC/RC in succession.

It runs until the following error

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Insert' of object 'Range' failed'

Comment: Shot in the dark: Change `Cell.Row` to `.Cell.Row` and try again

Comment: @SiddharthRout unfortunately not, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Ranges

- Assuming that all worksheets are in the workbook containing this code.
- Note that arrays will handle this more efficiently. Consider it as a lesson in ranges.
- Not tested.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub tracker()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Worksheets("Input check IC")
    Dim dst As Worksheet: Set dst = wb.Worksheets("Change tracker")
    Dim sws As Variant: ReDim sws(1 To 2)
    Set sws(1) = wb.Worksheets("Copy IC")
    Set sws(2) = wb.Worksheets("Live IC")
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = cws.Range("AI2:AI128")
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp) _
        .Resize(, 33).Offset(1, 0)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For n = 1 To 2
        Set srg = sws(n).Range("A2").Resize(crg.Rows.Count, 33)
        For i = 1 To crg.Cells.Count
            If crg.Cells(i).Value <> 0 Then
                drg.Value = srg.Rows(i).Value
                Set drg = drg.Offset(1)
            End If
        Next i
    Next n
                
    'Live IC
    sws(1).Range("B2:AG128").Value = sws(2).Range("B2:AG128").Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: run-time error 5 - invalid procedure call here: 'Set srg = sws(n).Cells("A2").Resize(crg.Rows.Count, 33'

Comment: Sorry, It is of course `Range("A2")`, not `Cells("A2")`. Corrected.

Comment: Executed perfectly, thank you so much! If you wouldn't mind, could you briefly explain why your method works and mine doesn't?

Comment: I would if I knew. I looked at it for quite a while and could only notice that although you have your ranges qualified, you don't have your worksheets qualified i.e. which workbook do they belong to. So I started 'translating' (the idea was that one loop has to go for sure) hoping I will bump into a mistake but I didn't. I can't say for sure that the unqualified worksheets are the reason, but that's all I could find being wrong.

Comment: I found another inaccuracy: try adding `.Cells` at the end of each `For Each` line i.e. it usually is written like this `For Each Cell in rng.Cells` i.e. you are looping through the **cells** of a range..